# How to fix TypeError: registerUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I am trying to register users  and add them to a database, but when I call the registerUser function, an error gets thrown.

I have read through [this article](https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/x-is-not-a-function-typeerror) to see how I would be causing this error and I have searched through several posts on here.

I feel like I must need another set of eyes to come and help find what I'm doing wrong

Here is the code that calls the register user function
('data' is an object that is the cleaned inputs from the sign-up form)

```
const db  = require('./database');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;


function hasher(data){

   bcrypt.hash(data.password, saltRounds)
      .then(function(hash) {
         data.password = hash;
         db.registerUser(data);  
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

if I console.log(db) before registerUser is called heroku prints "{}" in the logs

and this is the register user function from database.js:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const hasher = require('../models/hash')

const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

client.connect()


function registerUser(data) {

   const query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, email, username, hash_pass) VALUES(DEFAULT, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)";
   const values = [data.first, data.last, data.email, data.username, data.password];
   client.query(query, values)
      .then(res => console.log("stored: " + res.rows[0] + "in db"))
      .catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
}


module.exports = {
   registerUser : registerUser
};
```

I am getting "TypeError: db.registerUser is not a function"

Comment: Can you post what's in the database.js file and how function hasher(data) is being called?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, the second block of code is in the database.js file, I will edit to clarify

Comment: You exports looks good, where is `client` coming from, since is not in the database file?

How is hasher function being called?

Comment: I've added it in!  I'm just including 'pg' like what it says on https://node-postgres.com/api/client

Comment: @zac Can you `console.log(db)` right before calling `db.registerUser(data); ` and add the result to the question?

Comment: @leron if I console.log(db) before registerUser is called heroku prints "{}" in the logs, (I added that <-- to the question)

Comment: @zac well I'm not sure if this can be caused by circular dependency as `Ion` suggested. TBH his answer makes sense. However if you are sure that this should work you can try to export something simple like `module.exports = { registerUser : function() { return 'hello'; } }` and see if this time the console returns something.

Comment: @leron when I set did that and ```console.log(db.registerUser)``` it prints 'undefined' That points to Ion being right, right?

Comment: @zac Well at this point it's obvious that for one reason or another the function is never imported. Whether this is a result of circular dependency or not I can't say. If you don't get a concrete answer just try to reimplement the flow getting rid of the circular and using simple functions making sure that the scaffold works and then add the real behavior step by step. Sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: @leron It worked, I had to do a bit of researching into Promises, but I turned the hasher function into a promise and took the database call out and now it stores properly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I guess is that you are importing `const hasher = require('../models/hash')`  into `database.js` and `const db  = require('./database');` into hasher.

That circular dependency may be causing the problem.

Your exports are fine.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I turned the hasher function into a promise that just returns the password so now it doesn't call the database.

Answer (score 0):

From what  I can see `registerUser` is a standalone function, not a method of `db` object.

I can also see `module.exports = { registerUser : registerUser };` instruction - but this doesn't give a hint to where or what is it being exported to.

I suggest you try `registerUser(data);` as a standalone declaration and see what happens, because obviously it is not becoming a method of `db` - watch your console for any error messages during the load time...

good luck